# How do I apply a stylesheet from external URL to a specific react component

Tags: html, reactjs, sass, stylesheet

I have several web pages and I have this:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/superhero/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="full-height">
    <div id="app" class="full-height">Loading...</div>
</div>
</body>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

If i use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/superhero/bootstrap.min.css">
```

in index.html, styles in my entire app are affected but I want to use them in a single component.

I tried to solve this by removing those 2 lines and creating
chat.scss

```
#chat{
  @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");
  @import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/superhero/bootstrap.min.css");
}

//other import statements
import "../../styles/chat.scss"
```

then i set the id of the chat component to 'chat' and applied the scss

```
export default class Chat extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div id="chat">
            <div className="full-height">
                <div className="row">
                    <Nav/>
                </div>
                <div className="row full-height">
                    <div className="col-md-3 full-height">
                        <UserProfile/>
                        <OnlineUsers/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-9 full-height">
                        <div className="full-height">
                            <Messages/>
                            <MessageInput/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

This approach has same output as importing the styleshees in index.html. It affects all pages.

My question is how can I only apply those stylesheets for my chat component.

Comment: The approach you took is not valid as you noticed. I would recommend to customize bootstrap bundle using their tool: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/. This way, you can consume only the grid system (if that's what you're looking for). Also, it will reduce the bundle. It's pretty shame to load whole bootstrap for only one component and only one feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is a workaround I'm not proud of but this is how you can disable a stylesheet dynamically in javascript:

All stylesheets on the web page can be found inside of the document.styleSheets collection.
In order to grab the first one that caused me problems:

```
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
```

then i simply disabled it in my component:

```
stylesheet.disabled = true;
```